# Restarting router if offline

Tags: bash, cron, wget

My weird internet connection goes offline every day, weirdly, but I only need to restart the router and it will all be okay again.

So I decided to write script to restart the router, once it goes offline.

A `ping -c` was the first idea I thought of.,

After thinking through and researching, I came up with this:

```
wget -q --spider http://google.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Online"
    # do nothing
else
    echo "Offline"
    # retry for the next 2 minutes
    # and when still offline
    # curl command to restart router
fi
```

With that 2 minutes, it can compensate with the time it takes the router to reboot, question is how do I retry for the next 2 minutes.

Saving this in a file, and running as a cron every 7 minutes I think can do the job for me.

Answer (score -1):

I may have an answer

```
#!/bin/bash

retries=0

detect_network () {
  wget -q --spider http://google.com
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Online"
    retries=0
  else
    if [ "$retries" -eq 120 ]; then
      echo "curl now"
      #
    else
      echo "Offline"
      ((retries=retries+1))
      sleep 1
      detect_network
    fi
  fi
}

detect_network
```